# Which browsers support touch contact geometry? Will more do so in the future?

Tags: javascript, html, touch, multi-touch

I'd like to use the `radiusX`, `radiusY`, and `rotationAngle` attributes of (multi) touch events, but it appears they aren't part of the [current spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#attributes), just an [extension implemented by some browsers](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webevents/raw-file/tip/touchevents.html#attributes). Most browsers appear to only expose the location of each touch at this time.

I'm having a lot of trouble finding information about the current support (and future plans) for this type of touch geometry information, which seems really useful in some contexts. Is there a resource I've missed that provides this kind of information?